How to get the Microsoft Azure token , after login in native app, installed on iPhone
We have native application running on iPhone device, once we log into that application, we have a plugin which triggers another call to the silent or redirect login for the application.
Here the Microsoft Azure generates a token against the user logged in.
We need to get this token.
We are able to get the token in other devices or browsers but failing from iPhone device inside the native app.
Please let us know if anyone is aware or come across such issues. ?
Also if iFrame can work inside iPhone device ?
We have native application running on iPhone device, once we log into that application, we have a plugin which triggers another call to the silent or redirect login for the application.
Here the Microsoft Azure generates a token against the user logged in.
We need to get this token.
We are able to get the token in other devices or browsers but failing from iPhone device inside the native app.
Also if iFrame can work inside iPhone device ?
